# "illegal base64 data at input byte 20" in response from server

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am hitting an api in which i have to send header in request . I have used this method to convert

```
- (NSString*)encodeStringTo64:(NSString*)fromString {
    NSData *plainData = [fromString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *base64String;

    if ([plainData respondsToSelector:@selector(base64EncodedStringWithOptions:)])
    {
        base64String = [plainData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:kNilOptions];  // iOS 7+
    }
    else
    {
        base64String = [plainData base64Encoding];                              // pre iOS7
    }

    return base64String; }
```

but in response from Server i get this message :

> {
>       error = "invalid_request";
>       "error_description" = "illegal base64 data at input byte 20"; }

Please tell me what should i do?

Comment: error is for ios7+ or pre ios7?

Comment: @RonakChaniyara ios7+